# iOS Async Task ends and waits for 30 seconds to finish itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

i have an async sub class that finishes, and waits like 30 seconds after its done, if you can see, the nslog displays the OK answer, but it waits too long to put the same text that was displayed in the NSLOG, into the UILabel...
How can i break this?
this is the code:

```
-(BOOL) setParams{
    response.text = @"";
    //NSLog(@"Start:\r\n");
    [indicator setHidden:NO];
    [indicator startAnimating];
    if(pngData != nil){
        request = [NSMutableURLRequest new];
        request.timeoutInterval = 20.0;
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        [request setValue:@"text/html,<span id=\"IL_AD4\" class=\"IL_AD\">application</span>/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel <span id=\"IL_AD10\" class=\"IL_AD\">Mac OS X</span> 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/536.26.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.1 Safari/536.26.14" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        //Cada campo------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        NSString *keyName = @"add_product";
        NSString *keyValue = @"valRichard";

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",keyName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",keyValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //----La Imagen
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSString *imagePostName = @"imageToUpload";
        NSString *imagePostValue = @"x-cosa.png";

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",imagePostName, imagePostValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:pngData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [request setHTTPBody:body];
        [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

        return TRUE;

    }else{

        response.text = NO_IMAGE;

        return FALSE;
    }
}

- (IBAction) uploadImageAsync1:(id)sender
     {
      [indicator setHidden:NO];

    if([self setParams]){
    response.text = @"uploadImageAsync1";

        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue
            completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSData *data, NSError *error){
        NSString *theAnswer =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Finalizado: %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        NSLog(@"%@",theAnswer);
        //HERE IS THE CODE WHICH TAKES LIKE A MINUTE TO EXECUTE!!!!!
        [indicator stopAnimating];
        [indicator setHidden:YES];
        response.text = theAnswer;
        //END OF THE THREE LINES THAT EXECUTES AFTER
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = FALSE;
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error:%@", error.localizedDescription);
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UILabel is part of UIKit which is not thread-safe and should only be accessed from the main thread.  The `queue` parameter in `sendAsynchronousRequest:` is the queue that the completion handler gets called on, so you should pass it `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` so your completion handler is called on the main thread.